# Shiny App - Paging

Tags: r, shiny, widget, paging

I want to build a shiny web app where:

- First, a page appear for the users to input selection (e.g. drop down box, text field input etc.)
- There is a next button for the users to click which will direct them to the next page where they can input/answer another set of questions.
- Then in the last page, results (visualisations/analytics) are appearing based on their input.
- back button is available in case the users want to modify their answers/input

Are there any widgets/ways to do this ?

Any recommendations will be much appreciated :-)

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You could place the parts of your app in divs, and show and hide them with the shinyjs package. This also allows you to build in conditions for advancing to the next part of your app. See the example below. In this example, the user can only continue to section 2 if he answered the question in the first section.

Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id="div_1",
      h3('Section 1'),
      textInput("question1","what is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?"),
      actionButton("continue1","Continue.")
  ),
  shinyjs::hidden(div(id="div_2",
                      h3('Section 2'),
                      textInput("question2","what is your favorite color?"),
                      actionButton("continue2","Continue."),
                      actionButton("goback2","Go back!")
  )),
  shinyjs::hidden(div(id="div_3",
                      h3('Section 3'),
                      textOutput("results"),
                      actionButton("goback3","Go back!")
  ))

)
)


server <- function(input,output)
{
  observeEvent(input$continue1,{
    if(nchar(input$question1)>0)
    {
      shinyjs::hide("div_1")
      shinyjs::show("div_2")
    }
    else
    {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Important message",
        "How about you actually answer the question before continuing?"
      ))
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$continue2,{
    shinyjs::hide("div_2")
    shinyjs::show("div_3")
  })

  observeEvent(input$goback2,{
    shinyjs::hide("div_2")
    shinyjs::show("div_1")
  })

  observeEvent(input$goback3,{
    shinyjs::hide("div_3")
    shinyjs::show("div_2")
  })

  output$results <- renderText({paste0("Your answers were: '", input$question1,"' and '", input$question2, "'.") })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem? Thanks!